# Vue: Using the Vuex store in a JS class

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vue app where I am using Socket.io for live connections. I decided to put all the Socket calls into it's own `socket.js` class and  import the class into my Vue components. I've imported the store but I want to be able to save data to the Vuex store in this js file but I don't know how to do so outside of a .vue file.

**AppSocketIO.js**

```
import store from '../../../store';

class AppSocketIO {
    init() {
        this.socketIO = new AppSocketIO('kjiu887', {
          // run a mutation to save data to the Vuex store
        });
    }
```

**VueComponent**

```
mounted() {
    this.initSocket();
},
methods: {
    initSocket: function() {
        const socket = new AppSocketIO();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would do.  Leave the socket in a separate file.

```
socket.on('message', (data) => {
  store.commit('mutationName', data) // For mutations
  store.dispatch('actionName', data) // For actions
})
```

If your mutations/actions are namespaced, you'll have to keep that in mind.